# How to join tables where dates do not match

Tags: mysql

Reuploaded due to issues in dbfiddle.

I was presented this issue yesterday and I still can't answer it.

We have two tables and the aim is to find out how much revenue (price x quantity) the products made, bearing in mind the prices change (data on that held in pricing table). Affected date shows when the price changed.

It's specified you have to use mysql and not to use any window functions. I'm really stumped on this. Would appreciate a walk through the answer if possible, cheers.

the correct output is

```
1, 90 
2, 30
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f58c923811789eec1030d01e2fe8825e

Comment: It's hard to read a question when 75% of it is in some other web site. Why don't you paste here the short preparation script.

Comment: I used dbfiddle because it's the easiest way to illustrate the issue in practical terms and for someone to 'fiddle' with it, sorry. Not sure what you mean by preparation script

Comment: DBFiddle is great, but imho you need to present the table creation and insert statements as part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

> It's specified you have to use mysql and not to use any window functions.

Without window functions (MySQL 8.0.14 or above needed):

```sql
SELECT sales.ProductID, SUM(sales.Quantity * actual_pricing.price)
FROM sales,
LATERAL ( SELECT price
          FROM pricing
          WHERE pricing.ProductID = sales.ProductID
            AND pricing.affected_date <= sales.sale_date
          ORDER BY affected_date DESC LIMIT 1 ) AS actual_pricing
GROUP BY sales.ProductID
```

Without window functions and LATERAL (applicable even to 5.x):

```sql
SELECT sales.ProductID, SUM(sales.Quantity * p1.price)
FROM sales 
JOIN pricing p1 ON p1.ProductID = sales.ProductID
               AND p1.affected_date <= sales.sale_date
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM pricing p2
                   WHERE p2.ProductID = sales.ProductID
                     AND p2.affected_date <= sales.sale_date
                     AND p1.affected_date < p2.affected_date )
GROUP BY sales.ProductID
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=748ffdcc2b971bcfe10b9592eccb64ad)

Comment: That's great thanks, I've never even heard of a lateral join.
Could you perhaps explain the subquery in your solution without lateral please?

Comment: @stones91 [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Lateral Derived Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html)

Comment: *Could you perhaps explain the subquery in your solution without lateral please?* I join price to sale where price date is not above, and check that there is no another price between price and sale dates. Only last price matches.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go, just think how to filter out records in range

```
select s.ProductID, sum(s.Quantity * p.price) as revenue
from sales s
inner join pricing p 
   on s.ProductID = p.ProductID and p.affected_date <= s.Sale_Date
where not exists 
  (
    select * from pricing p2 
    where p2.ProductID = p.ProductId 
       and p2.affected_date <= s.Sale_Date 
       and p2.affected_date > p.affected_date
  )
group by s.ProductID;
```

Comment: looks like I've created duplicate